# Filtering a grouped list via the URL - Rows excluded from the filter showing if group contains filtered rows

Tags: list, filter, url

I am attempting to filter a list that is grouped by a field using parameters in the URL.

My url is ?FilterName=Status&FilterMultiValue=Approved;Review

As far as I know, this should return the rows containing either "Approved" or "Review" in them, excluding "Draft" status rows. What this actually does is return all the rows within a group, so long as at least one row contains either "Approved" or "Review" in the status field, meaning that rows with "Draft" in the status column are also being returned.

How come it does this? Can I stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. By default, grouped lists are set to be collapsed. If you change this to expanded by default, the list filters as expected. Another wonderful hidden feature of SharePoint maybe?